# Does the number of methods in a Java object affect how heavy it is?

Tags: java

I often read about heavy java objects and how making multiple instances of such objects can hamper performance. The singleton pattern is suggested as a solution to this problem. Correct me if am wrong , I think a heavy java object is one which has a huge number of variables or  variables which have a huge number of variables inside them leading to the consumption of large amount of memory. My question is , will a class which has a huge number of methods but very few variables also count as a heavy object?

Comment: Well, you should avoid creating god objects. The number of methods, by itself, is not a very good indication whether the object is heavy. When designing objects you should thrive for high cohesion and therefore low coupling.

Comment: 'Heavy' isn't a technical term in Java. It's just blog-speak for whatever you want it to mean. However method code is not duplicated per object instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heavy is a general concept that in this case means "everything that you consider bad for your application". It usually means: "takes long to construct" or "uses many scarce resources to construct (such as memory)".

In Java, more methods doesn't not mean "takes more memory", nor does it, in itself, influence how long it takes to construct the object, so it's not a concern for the heaviness of an object in Java.

Note that the singleton pattern has been largely superseded by *dependency injection* - where the decision on how many instances to create (one or more) is placed external to the code, in the configuration of the dependency injection.